# Is there a hotkey to switch between debug applications

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut to switch between running apps? I know how to switch tabs - alt+left/right, but I want to avoid clicking on HibernateTestApp, and do that via shortcut instead.

I've tried couple other shortcuts such as ctrl+alt+left/right and ctrl+shift+left/right, but no luck(

[image: apps_tabs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**. It is possible. Only pattern you didin't tried has solution. See Below **.....**

**`Alt` + `Down Arrow`**

It will show drop-down with all your running processes. You are done. :)

`Alt` + `Left/Right Arrow` will help you navigate between `console` and `debug`.